# PHP version is 4.4.9 when using exec() How do I change it on media temple without using .htaccess

Tags: php, mediatemple

I am using php version 5.3 on media temple's grid server, however when I call a file using exec() the page is executing in PHP version: 4.4.9

The reason I am using exec() is to process the file in the background.

This is probably a simple question, but how do I manually set the PHP version to 5.3 for this file without using .htaccess?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exec command?  Maybe you need to use a different path to PHP if that is part of the command (i.e. `exec('/usr/bin/php5 args')`)

Comment: PHP 4 absolutely resists to die...

Comment: Maybe you can change this behavior in the backend of mediatemple? http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/244/How+can+I+specify+the+PHP+version+on+the+%28gs%29+Grid-Service%3F This seems like a little bug at mediatemple.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario haha yeah, it's like an unwanted in-law. Keeps popping up to say hi, just when everyone hoped it was gone for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP interpreter you invoke via [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) is often a CGI version installed on the server as `/usr/bin/php`. You need to find out if a more contemporary version is available and then call the interpreter explicitly:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php-5.3  your-script.php  &");

# or just adapt your scripts shebang #!/usr/bin/php5
```

(Just an example, the filename will be different. Also you can usually leave out the path. It's mostly just security relevant for setuid binaries.)

You might find out about other versions via `print_r(glob("/usr/bin/php*"))`. But asking your hoster might be a better idea.

Comment: Hey thanks, that was really useful. I used print_r(glob("/usr/bin/php*")) found the right interpreter and voila it worked.